# Will my floor hold a wood-fired oven?

Tags: floor, joists, oven, load-bearing

I want to add a wood-fired oven to my house.  The room that I want to use was added on about 15 years ago and it's constructed on CMUs.  The floor joists are 2x10 spanning 14' doubled up at 12" OC.  The prior home owner had it built for a large hot tub.  The oven I'm looking at would be around 2,600 lbs. on a steel frame that is 36"x36" and on 4 legs.

I plan in having the oven as close to the corner of the room just to keep the room open.

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: Will depend on the design of the legs.  Much better to spread out the weight over the 9 square feet than have it on just four small area legs.  Plus most places will require non burning flooring(cement/cement board) under/around the stove adding to the weight, but maybe spreading the weight out more.  Will probably want an engineer to check.

Comment: It becomes more a matter of the base. Are the legs separate or on a bottom frame?

Comment: Beware of "cleances to combustibles" when putting it in the corner. You may not be able to get very close to the corner without setting the corner on fire. Support-wise, if the area below can be accessed, putting supporting lally columns directly under the where the legs hit the floor is the safest bet.

Comment: Based on the photos from the builder the legs look like they are 4” steel tubing  and the bottom might be 5” square.  My room will have tile and the oven can be as close as 2” from the surrounding walls.  By the way this is also known as a pizza oven

Comment: So no thoughts about if the floor will hold the oven?

Comment: Seems unlikely without additional support. That's a lot of very concentrated loading over 3 joists. To the extent that this odd situation can be put into a standard joist or beam calculator, (imprecise modeling as the load isn't distributed across the 3x14 area) it comes up a failure, which implies in the real case of a more concentrated load in a 3x3 foot area it's also a failure.

Comment: and this is based on 2x10s doubled up at 12 OC?

Comment: and this is based on 2x10s doubled up at 12 OC?

Comment: and this is based on 2x10s doubled up at 12 OC?